# SQL Server not difference between 'ی' and 'ي' in Arabic_CI_AS collation

Tags: sql-server, ascii, arabic, collation

I'm using ASCII function for getting equivalent ASCII code of two characters, but I'm surprised when seeing there is no difference between 'ي' and 'ی', can anyone help me?

```
SELECT ASCII('ي'), ASCII('ی')
```

Comment: this is my question too

Comment: The way you are selecting btw, gets the ASCII value of the first character. Those characters are of course not in the [ASCII code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). It's an american standard and has very few symbols. Arabic symbols are not part of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your character is non Unicode you have to use `UNICODE()` function instead of `ASCII()` .

```
SELECT ASCII('ي'), ASCII('ی')
```

will result: `237`, `237`

but

```
SELECT UNICODE(N'ي'), UNICODE(N'ی')
```

will result: `1610`, `1740`

Comment: This doesn't work as is - you get "63" returned for both. You need to mark your string literals as unicode with the `N` prefix - I'll edit it in for you, feel free to rollback if you think I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT UNICODE(N'ي'), UNICODE(N'ی')
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution by using the proper collate in case you want to use Ascii

```
Arabic_CS_AS_KS
```

result will come as ى = 236 and ي= 237

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation `ASCII` function. According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177545.aspx), `ASCII`:

> Returns the ASCII code value of the leftmost character of a character expression.

However, the characters in your question are made up of more than one byte. It appears that `ASCII` can only read one byte.

When you use these characters as string literals without the `N` prefix, they are treated as single-byte characters. The following query shows that SQL Server does not treat these characters as equal in the Arabic_CI_AS collation when they are properly marked as multi-byte:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'ي' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS <> 'ی' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS are_different_ascii,
CASE WHEN N'ي' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS <> N'ی' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS are_different_unicode
```

The following query shows the bytes that make up the characters:

```
SELECT CAST(N'ي' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS as varbinary(4)),
CAST(N'ی' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS as varbinary(4)),
CAST('ي' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS as varbinary(4)),
CAST('ی' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS as varbinary(4))
```

However, even when you mark the characters as unicode, the `ASCII` function returns the same value because it can only read one byte:

```
SELECT ASCII(N'ي' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS) , ASCII(N'ی' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS)
```

---

**EDIT** As TT. points out, these characters don't have an entry in the ASCII code table.

Answer (score 0):

The story becomes interesting when we have the following scripts:

```
SELECT ASCII('ك'), ASCII('ک');

SELECT
CASE
    WHEN 'ك' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS <> 'ک' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS are_different_ascii,
CASE WHEN N'ك' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS <> N'ک' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS are_different_unicode;
```

The letter ک and ك seems to be an exception!

Isn't that so?